# Wordpress cloning issue

Tags: linux, mysql

I have cloned my wordpress website **abc.com** using duplicator plugin. The clone is successfully installed and working on my other domain **abccopy.com**. But **abc.com/wp-login.php** page has a background image and a stylish login form. But **abccopy.com/wp-login.php** page has no image at all. Please help me how to copy login page as well.
All websites are running on CentOS 7.

Comment: Belongs on WordPress.stack exchange.com

Comment: i belvice your on the wrong site

Comment: That will depend on how you styled the login page on the original site: it won't use your theme, so I guess you've set up a plugin to hook login_enqueue_stylesheets or similar? Does that not work on the new site? Can you see the style included in view source? Can you see it load successfully in your browser debug tools network tab? Where is that script hosted?

Comment: Or did you edit the core WordPress stylesheets for the login page? That's the wrong way to do it, as it may get lost on a site update which would overwrite your edits, and I could well imagine that part wouldn't be cloned: the plugin would set up a clean WordPress core installation and just add database, content, plugins and theme.